# How can I dynamically access a JavaScript child class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, es6-class

I have a parent class with a bunch of children, each with very specific methods.

I need to loop through the array and basically each element will need to access a different child class. Is there any way to do this dynamically?

My classes currently look like this:

```
export default class MyParent {
  constructor (something) {
    // do constructor things
  }

  someMethod(param) {
    // do something
  }
}
.
.
.
export default class MyChildClass extends MyParent {
  constructor (something) {
    super(something)
  }

  someMethod(param) {
    // do something in overwritten method
  }
}
```

So basically I have a bunch of child classes, and now I need an array to go through them. Each element of that array will go through a different one of them.

```
export default function goThroughClasses (myArray) {
  const parentClass = new ParentClass(something)
  return myArray.map(arr => {
    // I would like this to go through all the different child methods instead of just the parent class
    // Note: the array does have data which would indicate which one
    // it should go through
    return parentClass.someMethod(arr)
    })
  )
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried putting all of the child classes into an array, each invoked with "[new childClass1(), new childClass2()]", etc. ? Looping through each such as a .forEach loop and try invoking a method on each iteration. Or insert all child classes into the array and on each iteration apply a "new childClass()" along with a method execution inside the block to check for data of the child class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an approach that can fit to your needs:

```
class Color {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  showColor() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

class Scent {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  showScent() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

const arr = [Color, Scent];

arr.forEach((childClass) => {
  const Child = new childClass('something here');
  if (Child.showColor) {
    console.log(Child.showColor());
  } else if (Child.showScent) {
    console.log(Child.showScent());
  }
});
```